# between query in couchbase

Tags: database, select, couchbase, between, sql++

I am using couchbase DB, I writed namedQuery buy I faced syntax error.
my date format : yyMMdd_HHmm

id :XX_YY_0038_2019-03-10@N**181025_1636**

```
SELECT meta().id FROM `TABLE_NAME` WHERE meta().id.SUBSTR(23,33) BETWEEN '181025_1650%' AND '181025_1730'
SELECT meta().id FROM `TABLE_NAME` WHERE substr(meta.id(),23,33) BETWEEN '181025_1711' AND '181025_1751'
SELECT meta().id FROM `TABLE_NAME` WHERE meta.id.substr(23,33) BETWEEN '181025_1711' AND '181025_1751'
```

how is should true syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the SUBSTR() function. This should work:

```
SELECT meta().id 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE SUBSTR(meta().id, 23) BETWEEN '181025_1650' AND '181025_1730'
```

You might need to adjust that starting-point (23).

Answer (score 1):

I am sharing my dynamic select query that get parameters from out

> String query = "SELECT meta().id FROM `" + bucketName + "` WHERE
>   SUBSTR(meta().id," + len + ") BETWEEN '" + dateStart + "'" + " AND " +
>   "'" + dateEnd + "'" + " AND meta().id LIKE '" + prefix + "%'";

```
public static Set<String> getDocument(String bucketName, Bucket bucket, String dateStart, String dateEnd, String key) {
    Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();
    String prefix = KEY_PREFIX + key;
    String len = String.valueOf(prefix.length());
    String query = "SELECT meta().id FROM `" + bucketName + "` WHERE SUBSTR(meta().id," + len + ") BETWEEN '" + dateStart + "'" + " AND " + "'" + dateEnd + "'" + " AND meta().id LIKE '" + prefix + "%'";
    N1qlQueryResult result = bucket.query(N1qlQuery.simple(query));
    for (N1qlQueryRow n1qlQueryRow : result) {
        keys.add(n1qlQueryRow.toString());
    }
    return keys;
}
```

Comment: Hi linda, thanks for contributing. Is this actually an answer to your question, or is this more information that should be part of your question? If it's an answer, you might want to provide a little more information.